# How can I change the look of ABPeoplePickerNavigationController so that i can see phone number type (home,mobile etc)

Tags: iphone, abpeoplepickerview

I am using ABPeoplePickerNavigationController in my app ,but client wants to see label of phone number infront of name say 
"Name  number type"
Ali     mobile
Ali     home 
is there a way to customize ABPeoplePickerNavigationController to fulfill this requirement?
thanks

Comment: Did you solve this ? if so can you post some code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to customize the address book according to your requirements, I suggest you should not use ABPeoplePickerNavigationController. Instead of that make the use of Address Book object, retrieve data from your address book and display those data in your custom ViewController.In this way you will be able to customize your View in whichever way you want.

Secondly you cannot modify the APIs and frameworks provided by Apple.

Comment: thanks.so what should i do ,whether i should customize it or not? but if customized it will take much time to include address book like functionality.....

Comment: @Ali to retrieve data from address book is not a big deal and once the data is fetched rest can be taken care of..

Comment: right data can be fetched easily but i need full addressbook like functionality and with additional phone label functionality ..

Comment: So you will have to implement the search bar at top,take a tableview controller to display names,take a custom cell to display names and numbers