# How add custom text to AddressBook contacts in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have working in a app for iPhone and I am getting de AddressBook contacts. I got it access to contact, but I wish add some text in some contacts (like WhatsApp), something like this:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUBRa.png]

Could someone help me please? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

See the [Table View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH1-SW1), especially [this section](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW11).
You will want to use `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle`.

Comment: Hello vikingosegundo. Thank you for you response, but I'm not sure that's what I'm looking. I am using ABPeoplePickerNavigationController to show the contacts on my phone and I can't modify it controller. How I should do to add this information to ABPeoplePickerNavigationController or ABAddressBookRef contacts?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688072/how-can-i-change-the-look-of-abpeoplepickernavigationcontroller-so-that-i-can-see

Comment: Thanks vikingosegundo. It seems the only option I have left to me is do I manually so that it looks like the address book, right?