# GroupMe Contacts | Address Book

Tags: ios, uitableview, abaddressbook, abpeoplepickerview

I want to build a `ContactsTableViewController` like that of [GroupMe](http://groupme.com/). It shows all my Address Book contacts and even which ones are GroupMe users.

[image]

It seems that [ABPeoplePickerNavigationController cannot be customized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688072/how-can-i-change-the-look-of-abpeoplepickernavigationcontroller-so-that-i-can-se/4688142#4688142).

1. So, if I access Address Book contacts with `ABAddressBook` & `ABPerson`, what's the best way to display them with a custom `UITableViewController`?

   I don't want to just load all Address Book contacts into an `NSArray` because that could kill the memory (I know people who have thousands of Address Book contacts on their phones.). I'm used to using Core Data & `NSFetchedResultsController` for large result sets like this. But, to do that, I'd have to create an `ABPerson` model in Core Data, which would be easy, but keeping it in sync with the Address Book seems challenging and sort of silly.
2. What's the best way to relate/link GroupMe contacts to Address Book contacts?
3. Is there anything else I should know/consider when trying to recreate this GroupMe-style interface?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm one of the GroupMe iOS developers and this is what we do.

1. We scan the users address book and store it in Core Data. We have a Contact object that has a 1-to-many against phone numbers, and a 1-to-many against email addresses. The first scan can take a little time if there a lot of contacts, but in each subsequent scan we ignore any `ABRecordRef` that has a `kABPersonModificationDateProperty` before our last scan. This makes updates a lot faster.
2. Then, assuming the user has opted into syncing contacts, we upload phone numbers and email addresses to our server which will match against existing GroupMe users.
3. Finally, we pull GroupMe relationships based on matches (from phone, email, facebook, twitter) and store those in Core Data as well. If relationship was made because of a phone/email already existing in the user's address book, we pass those values back in the relationships so we can create a 1-to-1 relationship between the GroupMe relationship and the contact we stored in Core Data in step 1. This way we can easily create `NSFetchRequest`s for local contacts, or GroupMe relationships and have their relationship details available at any point (so we can show that a local contact is a GroupMe user etc -- like Aaron G. in your screenshot)

We use a `NSFetchedResultsController`, as well, so we can get updates reflected in the UI if our background operations find any new contacts/relationships..

The only other tips are to make sure you have your fetch request prefetch all relationships so loading relationship reasons don't hit core data as you scroll to populate faults.

And yeah, while keeping your Core Data n'sync with the user's address book is more tedious than silly, it's worth it so you can have easy access to it and for queries that need to know all that jazz.

Comment: if you wouldn't mind looking at this to let me know what sort of service you use as the phone number the text gets sent to - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11954720/how-did-groupme-verify-my-number. I'd rather not speculate when I can just ask one of the actual developers

Comment: @jeremysomething - you mentioned you're able to fetch relationships based on matches (phone or email contact)- does apple provide the date/timestamp when this relationship was established?

Comment: is it not depend on phone's time, phone time can be changed by the user. How you have overcome from that problem?