# Access user's phone number on iOS 7

Tags: ios7, phone-number

I know that iOS 4 and 5 do not allow the access of a user's phone number since its outside the sandbox of an application (if it needs to be accepted by apple).
I would like to know whether this has changed in iOS 7 - with permissions whether it can be accessed etc.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

No.  Apple APIs do not provide access to this information. What's more, attempting to get this information without asking the user is generally considered a huge breach of privacy.

Comment: If you could back up your answer with the latest apple doc snippet/link, that would be a bonus :)

Comment: What's the best reason you have seen for Apple disallowing permission-based access to the user's phone number? Apple already allows permission-based access to contacts and photos, and the user's camera and microphone. Why not the phone number? There must be a good reason, but it's not immediately clear.

Answer (score 4):

"For security reasons, iPhone OS restricts an application (including its preferences and data) to a unique location in the file system. This restriction is part of the security feature known as the application's "sandbox." The sandbox is a set of fine-grained controls limiting an application's access to files, preferences, network resources, hardware, and so on."

The device's phone number is not available within your application's container.

**please find apple response in this link [apple response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193182/programmatically-get-own-phone-number-in-ios)**

i found some thing interesting here [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11954720/how-did-groupme-verify-my-number)

thanks