# Get the mobile number from iPhone settings in titanium appcelerator

Tags: iphone, titanium, titanium-mobile

I want to  fetch the user's phone number from her iPhone settings. I have found so far that this is not supported with any Titanium API. Is there any module or a way to get the phone number that is entered in user's iPhone settings.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access that information. Even when you are using Objective-C to create your app, Apple doesn't provide API for that. Take a look on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20259896/access-users-phone-number-on-ios-7).

If you want to collect users phone numbers, you have to ask them for it explaining why you need it.